# How to establish Excel connections using SSH Keys where the ODBC driver itself does not include SSH. Can this be done in the Excel connection string?

Tags: excel, ssh, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up an Excel connection to Snowflake leveraging an SSH key for the connection.  The Snowflake ODBC driver does not directly support SSH Key.

My company will only permit SSO or SSH connections and the SSO connection has painful performance.  I have heard that SSH connections are possible for Excel with ODBC and that the performance is much better.

As Excel connects to ODBC sources, there is the "advanced option" of writing connection string information.  I suspect this is how SSH Keys can be set up.

Can anyone point in the right direction?

Comment: How does SSO affect the connector performance?

Comment: You can use key/pair authentication as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html) if you don't want SSO. Do you have any proof that SSO has impact on performance?